# Users still can login although email and password that insert is wrong,why?

Tags: php, mysql

I am quite new in php language..currently i am working on a login and registration system.but i dont know why the users still can login to the although the email and password insert is wrong,since i already make all the validation.So,guys,pls help me to see my code,see whether where the problem is.

here is my code

```
<?php
include('config.php');

    session_start();

    $errors=array();

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($email&&$password){

        //declare variable
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' Password=''$password");
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        //when user correct input,check the data 
        if($numrows !== 0) {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $dbemail=$row['Email'];
                $dbpassword=$row['Password'];
            }
            //if username and password match
            if($dbemail=$email&&$dbpassword=$password)
            {
                $SESSION['$email']="$email";
                header('Location:user.html');

            }

            else
            {
                $errors['notcorrect'] = "Email or password not correct";
            }
        } 
        //when insert wrong data
        else{
            $errors['notexists'] = "This email doesn't exists";
        }
    }
    //when user didnt enter anything
    else{
        $errors['nothing'] = "Please enter your email and password";
    }
}

?>
```

any idea?

Comment: Examine this => `Password=''$password"` and this `$SESSION` and this `if($dbemail=$email&&$dbpassword=$password)`.

Comment: add it at where ya??

Comment: where to put this actually??@Fred-ii-

Comment: It's not "where to put", it's "how to fix".

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: You're wide open to an SQL injection attack http://xkcd.com/327/ - Also, you aren't using an AND in your SQL query so it might not be syntatically correct, and your code implies that you're storing passwords as plaintext which is a suicidally bad idea.  You might want to look into fixing all three of these flaws.

Comment: @ken I made a slight edit also, therefore you will need to reload my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's examine these in detail:

- `Password=''$password"`
- `$SESSION`
- `if($dbemail=$email&&$dbpassword=$password)`
- `WHERE Email='$email' Password=''$password")`
- `$_SESSION['$email']="$email";`

`$password` is outside your quotes.

Then `$SESSION` is missing an underscore between the `$` and `SESSION`.

- This is also a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Then you're "assigning" using 1x `=` sign instead of "comparing" with `if($dbemail=$email&&$dbpassword=$password)`

Use 2x `==` signs.

You're missing an `AND` for `WHERE Email='$email' Password=''$password")`

```
WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'");
```

You should also, and is recommended to add `exit;` after header.

```
header('Location:user.html');
exit;
```

Otherwise, your code risks in continuing to execute.

`$_SESSION['$email']="$email";` there is a dollar sign in `['$email']`

It needs to read as `['email']`.

---

Sidenote:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Footnote(s):

1. In regards to `Location:user.html` are you sure you want to use an `.html` file? If you're not instructing Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP and with no conditional statement to check if the session is set and equal to what you've assigned to it, then anyone can access that file.
2. I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

It is recommended to use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

- As the chinese proverb goes: *"Show a man how to fish, feed him for life."*

Comment: @ken You've very much welcome Ken, *cheers* Glad I could help.

Comment: so for the $_SESSION where should i put??is it within the if statement?since is a superglobal?

Comment: @ken You can leave it where it is now. But add the underscore `$_SESSION['email']="$email";` and you don't need the quotes around `$email` - `$_SESSION['email']=$email;` - and there was a dollar sign in there which escaped me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're on a hot streak. It's like at least five accepted answers in a row. :)

Comment: @JohnConde I guess I like to make sure of my shot before I go up to bat ;-)

Comment: @JohnConde Actually, it's more like 10 ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- complete and detailed answer as usual ! :)

Comment: @meda Aye, I figured I could explain it for the OP to understand where the faults were. Seems like it worked too :-) says they learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Update this

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password' ");
```

And also correct the session super global from $SESSION to $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an assignment here where you should be doing a comparison:

```
if($dbemail=$email&&$dbpassword=$password)
```

Should be

```
if($dbemail == $email && $dbpassword == $password)
```

Whitespace makes things more readable.

Answer (score 0):

the error in select query you forgot and operator

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='{$email}' AND Password='{$password}' ");
```

And change the equle operator in if statment with `===` like this

```
if($dbemail===$email&&$dbpassword===$password)
```

I hope that works successfully

Comment: I edited your answer, use 4 spaces for code blocks, and ` for smaller snippets. I didn't fix the spelling errors though

Answer (score -1):

Update your code

```
<?php
include('config.php');

    session_start();

    $errors=array();

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($email&&$password){

        //declare variable
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'");
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        //when user correct input,check the data 
        if($numrows !== 0) {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $dbemail=$row['Email'];
                $dbpassword=$row['Password'];
            }
            //if username and password match
            if($dbemail==$email && $dbpassword==$password)
            {
                $_SESSION['$email']="$email";
                header('Location:user.html');
                die();
            }

            else
            {
                $errors['notcorrect'] = "Email or password not correct";
            }
        } 
        //when insert wrong data
        else{
            $errors['notexists'] = "This email doesn't exists";
        }
    }
    //when user didnt enter anything
    else{
        $errors['nothing'] = "Please enter your email and password";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The SQL query is still invalid.

Comment: @ken fixed `SQL` query changed `$SESSION` to `$_SESSION` and used `=` to `==`